# Flatten Nested Dict from pandas Dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `for` loop that is looping over a list for completing an API call. With each loop I have the `json` response run through `pandas` and `append` to `REPL_ID`:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

REPL_ID = []

REPL = ["node01%4000-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390%5B1-1-2D%5D",
        "node02%4000-B700F9-869677-4991B3-79CBE2%5B1-1-2E%5D",
        "node03%4000-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8%5B1-1-19%5D"
       ]

def get_id():
    for value in REPL:
        url = func_repl(value)
        r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, verify=False)

        jsonstring = json.dumps(r.json()["replication"])
        load = json.loads(jsonstring)
        df = json_normalize(load)
        df['NodeId'] = pd.Series(df.itemNodeId)
        df['ID'] = pd.Series(df.id).str.replace("{", "").str.replace("}", "")
        col = ['NodeId', 'ID']
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=col)
        x = df1.to_dict('index')
        REPL_ID.append(x)
    return
```

After it completes, I have it `print` the contents of `REPL_ID`.

**Output from REPL_ID:**

```
[{
  0: {'NodeId': 'node01@00-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390[1-1-2D]',
      'ID': '006bdade-49a8-4875-93de-54ba356403c4'},
  ...
  20: {'NodeId': 'node01@00-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390[1-1-2D]',
      'ID': 'f8613a7d-30b1-4407-82f0-b92c82c6c422'}
  }, {
  0: {'NodeId': 'node03@00-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8[1-1-19]',
      'ID': '065999f6-a3fe-4b1d-af35-7556efcc530e'},
  ...
  27: {'NodeId': 'node03@00-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8[1-1-19]',
      'ID': 'cf96419c-a188-4b1a-85d6-bde41dbbe3ef'}
}]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[{
  0: {'NodeId': 'node01@00-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390[1-1-2D]',
      'ID': '006bdade-49a8-4875-93de-54ba356403c4'}
  ...
  78: {'NodeId': 'node03@00-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8[1-1-19]',
      'ID': 'cf96419c-a188-4b1a-85d6-bde41dbbe3ef'}
}]
```

I'm having trouble flattening and reindexing this list. How can this be done?

I'm only collecting this information for completing the next API call which requires both `NodeId` and `ID`.

Comment: What are the differences between your current and desired outputs? It looks like a nested dict to me, but missing commas between items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to implement directly in your code but you can just take an extra step with your output. Simply loop over your dic of dics  {{},{},...}, take each dic and add each entry (key/values) to a new dic leading to one unnested dic.

```
original_output = [{
  1: {'NodeId': 'node01@00-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390[1-1-2D]',
      'ID': '006bdade-49a8-4875-93de-54ba356403c4'},
  2: {'NodeId': 'node01@00-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390[1-1-2D]',
      'ID': 'f8613a7d-30b1-4407-82f0-b92c82c6c422'}
  }, {
  5: {'NodeId': 'node03@00-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8[1-1-19]',
      'ID': '065999f6-a3fe-4b1d-af35-7556efcc530e'},
  6: {'NodeId': 'node03@00-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8[1-1-19]',
      'ID': 'cf96419c-a188-4b1a-85d6-bde41dbbe3ef'}
}]


new_dict = {}
c = 0 
for dic in original_output:
    for key in dic.keys():
        new_dict[c] = dic[key]
        c += 1
new_dict

Out:
{0: {'NodeId': 'node01@00-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390[1-1-2D]',
  'ID': '006bdade-49a8-4875-93de-54ba356403c4'},
 1: {'NodeId': 'node01@00-68D6FB-65377D-4804B8-A7F390[1-1-2D]',
  'ID': 'f8613a7d-30b1-4407-82f0-b92c82c6c422'},
 2: {'NodeId': 'node03@00-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8[1-1-19]',
  'ID': '065999f6-a3fe-4b1d-af35-7556efcc530e'},
 3: {'NodeId': 'node03@00-94CF47-90E188-48728F-0538D8[1-1-19]',
  'ID': 'cf96419c-a188-4b1a-85d6-bde41dbbe3ef'}}
```

EDIT: added the 'reindexing' via the c variable

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tested your code and it looks like it merges the output based on the index value. For example, the output of each node index starts at 0 and goes to 20 (node01), 31 (node02), and 27 (node03). In the returned output it gave me only node03 (0 through 27) then node02 (28 through 31).

Comment: You're right. I didn't generate a new key. Let me edit it.